# java.lang.NullPointerException at java.util.Calendar.setTime

Tags: java, date

**Get null when trying to format a date.**

The value of `theTxn.getTxnRptSettleDate()` is `2017-02-03`.

I try to format it by apply formula below but get null

```
SimpleDateFormat dateformatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
System.out.println(dateformatter.format(theTxn.getTxnRptSettleDate()));
```

**Error**

```
18:37:01,837 ERROR SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1 AbstractStep:185 - Encountered an error executing the step: class java.lang.NullPointerException: null
Exception in thread "SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Calendar.setTime(Calendar.java:1770)
18:37:01,896  INFO SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1 SimpleJobLauncher:87 - Job: [org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContextJobFactory$ContextClosingJob@5bbde32d] failed with the following parameters: [{}{}{}{schedule.DATE=Sun Apr 15 00:00:00 MYT 2018}]
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.format(SimpleDateFormat.java:943)
    at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.format(SimpleDateFormat.java:936)
    at java.text.DateFormat.format(DateFormat.java:345)
```

If I remove the `dateformatter`, it runs well:

```
System.out.println(theTxn.getTxnRptSettleDate()); //works fine
```

Comment: Is your simpledateformat shared between threads?

Comment: Your actual date and format for date differs. Should it be like yyyy-MM-dd?

Comment: @CuriousMind He's not parsing, he's formatting.

Comment: @assylias Nope...I'm using it in Spring

Comment: Aha, my mistake.

Comment: I get `2017-03-02` if I remove the formatter

Comment: @assylias yes...

Comment: @JohnJoe Where do you create the `SimpleDateFormat`? on the line above like in your example or is it a field in your class?

Comment: @assylias Time for bed :P - still raises the question of how they achieved that result :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer Go to sleep then. Enjoy

Comment: @assylias Is afield in my class

Comment: @JohnJoe It really looks like a threading issue to me - SimpleDateFormat is not thread safe so should probably not be a field anyway. Do you get the same error if you create it as a local variable directly within your method?

Comment: Yes,same error.

Comment: What output do you get if you run this **exact** code: `System.out.println(theTxn.getTxnRptSettleDate()); System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(theTxn.getTxnRptSettleDate()));`

Comment: @assylias `2017-03-02
null
19:16:51,685 ERROR SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1 AbstractStep:185 - Encountered an error executing the step: class java.lang.NullPointerException: null
Exception in thread "SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
19:16:51,744  INFO SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1 SimpleJobLauncher:87 - Job: ...`

Comment: `2017-03-02 null` ? There's something...

Comment: @assylias Really strange.

Comment: Not sure what's going on - but Date::toString can't print null. So it looks like you are printing another date somewhere (2017-03-02) and that later on you print `theTxn.getTxnRptSettleDate()` which is null.

Comment: @assylias https://pastebin.com/MbeAF6Ui

Comment: @JohnJoe Looks like you have a collection with 3 or more dates - the first two are fine but the third one is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting is NullPointerException and it's all related to the values you are setting and getting.

You are setting a null value to calendar time...

try debugging your code and check the values returned at each point.

when i was facing the problem at starting then i used a trick. 
don't know if it's good or bad but this must work.
The standard format is yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS

so just add very sincerely 00:00:00 in the last and then send to formatter.
like if i have 2017-06-02 then do it `2017-06-02 00:00:00`

Just give it a try. I know it's not a standard solution, but this worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

The method *theTxn.getTxnRptSettleDate()* is returning null , since format method will throw "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date" if non-compliant object is passed. Tested it locally on various scenarios and only when the argument passed is **null** , does the **NullPointerException** is thrown , with the same call stack as in your case.

Kindly verify the same by logging the return of  *theTxn.getTxnRptSettleDate()* and also do a reflection test on the object returned to confirm.